# How to exclude a path (directory) via RegEx

Tags: regex

I am new to regex, currently we use some regex to transfer files and folders from Source to destination, source has everything, destination only contains subset of it. one of regex is to exclude the folders named assets and its files with it, but now I want to make a exception, i have a new folder in source root named test, in that folder it contains a folder named assets as well, I would like to exclude it via regex.

1. on the source directory

   - assets/...
   - a/assets/..
   - b/assets/..
   - c/d/assets/
2. on the destination I would like to have

   - assets/..
   - a/assets/..
   - c/d/assets/..

basically just exclude the assets under b

Cheers

Comment: I don't understand what you want. Please give a list of example strings you want to match, and another list of edge cases that don't match.

Comment: Have you tried a regex yet? If so show what you have tried already. Do these path's begin with drive letters?

Comment: You say "we use some regex" - Perhaps it would be illuminating if you were to share that regex with us.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do this via a single Regex as you require looking at previous items in a collection.

You're best bet would be to create a tree structure and create a custom node object which will identify if its children already contain a specific value.

Once you have built your tree fully you can iterate back through it and build a folder for each Node your tree now contains.

There are lots of example on the internet for creating Tree structures.